# Реализация сематики указателя (прокси класс)

Tags: c++

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    void foo() {}
};

class MyObjectPtr // Так называемый PROXY класс
{
    MyObject* ptr_;
public:
    MyObjectPtr()
        : ptr_(new MyObject())
    {
    }

    ~MyObjectPtr()
    {
        delete ptr_;
    }

    MyObject* operator->()
    {
        return ptr_;
    }
};

MyObjectPtr p;
p->foo();
```

Здесь оператор -> возвращает указатель на MyObject и после вызываем функцию foo().
Однако, мне кажется было бы логичнее, если бы вызов функции выглядел вот так:

```
(p->)->foo();
```

Разве нет? Сначала мы получаем указатель, а после происходит обращение через указатель к функции класса.
Или я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: `operator->` - особенный в плане синтаксиса.

Comment: Это уже будет **не** семантика указателя...

Comment: Еще, не хватает копирующего конструктора и оператора присваивания (и перемещающих тоже) - без них таким классом сложно нормально пользоваться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в процессе изучения. Но спасибо, учту это

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Про особенный тоже принял к сведению, пока это единственное объяснение для меня

Comment: Всё для красоты. Без оператора `->` выглядело бы так: `p.Ptr()->foo();` То-есть лишних шесть букв.

Answer (score 1):

Что такое "семантика указателя"? Это когда объект выглядит как указатель.

То есть ваш `MyObjectPtr p;` должен вести себя как указатель:

```
p->foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

да, Вы верно описываете функциональность класса MyObjectPtr. Оператор -> возвращает указатель на MyObject и вы можете вызывать функцию foo() у этого указателя.

НО, выражение (p->)->foo() не будет работать, поскольку p-> уже возвращает указатель на MyObject, а не другой указатель. Поэтому вызов функции foo() должен выглядеть как p->foo().

Comment: Второй абзац не понял. `(p->)->foo()` не работает потому, что после `->` всегда должно идти имя члена.

Comment: объект -> метод или его имя