# Семантика указателя C++. Почему operator-> не возвращает указатель как положено

Tags: c++

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void foo() const { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

template <class T>
class UniqPtr
{
private:
    T* ptr_;
public:
    UniqPtr(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}
    
    T* operator-> () { return ptr_; }

    ~UniqPtr() { delete ptr_; }
};

int main()
{
    UniqPtr<UniqPtr<Foo>> q(new UniqPtr<Foo>(new Foo()));
    (q->)->foo(); // ERROR
}
```

Почему я не могу сделать так? Это же вроде логично...

Comment: Ошибку приводите. А вообще мне кажется, что вы просто запутались в уровне пренаправления. Ведь чтобы вызвать перегруженный оператор `->` необходимо иметь ссылку на экземпляр класса `UniqPtr`, а не указатель.

Comment: Потому что, как я уже писал вам в предыдущем вопросе, справа от `->` должно быть написано имя поля или метода. Там не может быть чего-то другого, например `)`. Чтобы просто вызвать `operator->`, не выбирая конкретное поле, можно сделать `q.operator->()`, как написали в ответе ниже.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Реализация сематики указателя (прокси класс)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1495901/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая стрелка возвращает указатель и он имеет тип `UniqPtr<Foo>*`, а класс `UniqPtr<Foo>` не имеет метода `foo` и происходит ошибка. Вам нужно ещё разыменование указателя с помощью звёздочки, чтобы получить сам объект . Примерно так :

```cpp
(*(q->))->foo();
```

Но данная запись опять приведёт к ошибке, так как укороченный вариант `(q->)` требует только метод или поле. *Работать будет только в простых случаях.*

В вашем случае укороченный вариант пропускаем и вызываем прямой вызов оператора так :

```cpp
(*(q.operator->()))->foo();
```

---

Вариант II

```cpp
q->operator->()->foo();
```

`q->` возвращает тип `UniqPtr<Foo>*`
`operator->()` возвращает тип `Foo*`
`->foo()` уже вызывает метод.

Comment: Теперь понял. Благодарю)